# Google Apps Scripts: How to save files from root to a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm starting to learn google apps script and suffering a little, :S.

So, when I run this function:

```
function importXLSX(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B5HXuvZIdqQ3bWlKNXFXZzhIcmc').searchFiles('title contains ".xlsx"');
    while(files.hasNext()){
      var xFile = files.next();
      var name = xFile.getName();
         if (name.indexOf('.xlsx')){ 
            var ID = xFile.getId();
            var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
            var newFile = { title : name+'_converted',
                 key : ID,
            }
            file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
            convert: true
            });
         }
       }
    }
```

The files converteds are set in Drive's root, but I´d like that

When I run the code, the files are saved in the root folder but I would like them to be saved to a specific folder, like "Converteds", so if anyone knows how to solve it, I would be very grateful!

This is a reference link about the function: [Convert all xls files available in a folder into "Google Doc Spreadsheets"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368143/convert-all-xls-files-available-in-a-folder-into-google-doc-spreadsheets/44205268#44205268)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you use Drive API, you can directly create a file to the specific folder.

I added `parents: [{"id": "### Folder ID ###"}]` to `newFile`. Please change `### Folder ID ###` to the specific folder and try this.

**Modified script :**

```
function importXLSX(){
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B5HXuvZIdqQ3bWlKNXFXZzhIcmc').searchFiles('title contains ".xlsx"');
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    if (name.indexOf('.xlsx')) { 
      var ID = xFile.getId();
      var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
      var newFile = {
        title : name+'_converted',
        key : ID,
        parents: [{"id": "### Folder ID ###"}]
      }
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {convert: true});
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to retrieve folder ID from folder name. Please use following script.

```
var folderId = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("### Folder name ###").next().getId();
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: awesome! The script is working very well! Thanks a lot! If I can ask one more question: to insert the date in the title, like "name+'_converted', what I have to do?

Comment: For example,please change ``title :`` to ``title : name+'_converted_' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date() , 'GMT', 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'),``. ``GMT`` is timezone. If you want to use other timezone, please change it. Also you can change freely the date format.

Comment: Great, @Tanaike! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the Folder id (right-click the folder in Google Drive and check its share options by clicking "Get Shareable Link", the string at the tail-end of the share URL is the folder's id) and then for each file you convert add the file to the target folder.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById([folder-id]);

while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    ...
    ...
    folder.addFile(file);
}
```

And that should do the trick!

Comment: Hey, @Dimu Designs, really thanks for responding. Where should I put the    folder.addFile(file);    before the last } ? I think that I'm wrong with this.