# Is there an option to receive data from Excel to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I need some data (text/numbers) from specific columns or rows of EXCEL to be received into Google Sheets.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2):

you need to upload your excel file to Drive convert it to Sheets and use `IMPORTRANGE` to extract given range into your spreadsheet.

uploading can be automated via **https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/**

conversion can be automated via **https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645062/5632629**

and `IMPORTRANGE` formula syntax is:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_ID_here"; "sheet_name_here!A1:D20")
```